# OneToMany and ManyToOne Relationship

Tags: jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have 2 tables mapped @OneToMany and @ManyToOne and their setters and getters, so a user can have multiple transactions and a transaction could have only one user.

If I add a transaction in the User's list data goes into the table correctly and transaction can be retrieved by using User's getter. But when I use getter from the Transaction to find its owner, it doesn't find its respectively user from users table.

Reverse is also available, if I set a user for a transaction data is persisted in database and user can be retrieved by using Transaction's getter, but use of User's getter doesn't show any transaction..

The only way is to add a transaction in the User's list and set user for the transaction. Why is this happening? I thought that if I use only one of this actions the reverse should be available automatically.

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Collection<Transaction> transactions;
```

Transaction

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_transactions")
public class Transaction{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;
```

I can't see any difference in tables, any action I do both tables have the same structure. How does JPA know how I saved the objects and build them back again...?

Comment: It's happening because that's how JPA is specified. It uses POJOs, and if you leave a field to null, the field will be null. If you don't add a transaction to a list, the list won't contain the transaction. It's up to you to maintain the coherence of your objects. JPA will give you back coherent objects when reading them from the database, though.

Comment: but is there any other way to make this work as I want?

Comment: No. If you want to add a transaction to a user, and set the user of the transaction, you need to code it. JPA won't do that for you.

Comment: I can't see any difference in tables, any action I do, both tables have the same structure. So it could very well say that I have added a transaction in the list or to believe that I have setted a User for transaction. How does JPA know how I saved those objects and build them back again...?

Comment: It doesn't need to know how you created objects. As I said, JPA will do the right thing when it populates the objects from the database: the transaction will have ts user set, and the user will have its transactions in the list. But when *you* create these objects, *you* are responsible for setting the transaction's user and for adding the transaction to the list.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember there is no  default CascadeType.
You must specify one, for example in your case:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<Transaction> transactions;
```

you can read about cascade types here :
http://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-jpa-cascade-types/